# How to correctly type an array function?

Tags: typescript

Let's say that I have a custom function that I've written that loops over an array:

```js
function find(array, callback, context) {

    const {
        length
    } = array;
    let index = 0;

    while (index < length) {

        if (callback.call(context, array[index], index, array)) {
            return index;
        }

        index += 1;

    }

    return -1;

}
```

Let's further say that I want to properly type it using TypeScript:

```js
function find(
    array: ArrayLike<any>,
    callback: (this: typeof context, item: any, index: number, array: ArrayLike<any>) => boolean,
    context?: any
) {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a better way to describe the parameters? I'd like to be able to say that the `item` parameter in the callback has the same type as the `array` items (although the actual type doesn't matter). I'd also like to be able to say that both `array` references are the same thing.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html (and I guess you knew this, but that's [already a method on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use a generic parameter:

```
// TypeScript
function find<T>(
    array: ArrayLike<T>,
    callback: (this: typeof context, item: T, index: number, array: ArrayLike<T>) => boolean,
    context?: any
) {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFMGUDGAnAltALgKAGYFcA7RDVAewNB1QIBMAecAPgAotR3QBDZZTyALlABBHnwAyqANawGjADRsOiTgBsVAI06JJg5hgAWqAM6CMMWKRyhE5DLAAeGOaFR2AtoPDPqNB4IJ4buqwyM7cvALCopAS0rIAlKAAvIyg6qSkKrCcBAoc1rYOGAD8gjmQWIkA3orsIKAAdE1YAL5YWDYERhhcPMmgANoAjHIATHIAzAC67VS0zOHOzK6wbt60DmHRiSmgGMh4sPFYIAB6xUA)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [generic parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). One parameter `T` for the arrays which enforces all `array` items to have the same type. No matter what type unless you add a [constraint using `extend`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). And another parameter `Ctx` to make sure both context parameters have the same type.

```js
function find<T, Ctx>(
  array: ArrayLike<T>,
  callback: (
    this: Ctx,
    item: T,
    index: number,
    array: ArrayLike<T>
  ) => boolean,
  context?: Ctx
) {
  //implementation
}
```

Comment: Does `this: typeof context` not already handle the `Ctx` part?

Comment: `context?` is typed as `any`. So `this` will be of type `any` as well. If you really don't care what type it is you're absolutely fine. However, adding this constraint gives you better intellisense than just `any`.

Comment: Since the context is optional and probably won't be used, I think it's fine in my specific context. Good shout for improved intellisense though